# Weird shadows, what is it?

Tags: shadows

weird shadows only on cylinders, how can i fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

That happens when i always use spin mode

Comment: hello could you please share this object only?

Comment: yes,, in process

Comment: Hello, I can't see any link  ;)

Comment: i added a photos above

Comment: i meant share the file (only the object with the problem), you can use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or a platform like workupload

Comment: oh, okay wait a second)

Answer (score 0):

Your object is highly scaled, apply the scale in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and it should fix your shading problem (maybe shade smooth again as well):

[image]

Result before and after:

[image]

Comment: but if i change, then my model will change too

Comment: if you apply the scale it won't change your object visually

Comment: okay, i tried, but it's desn't work, even with new cylinders, shadows always crushes when i use spin

Comment: well it works for me, maybe shade smooth again after applying the scale?

Comment: Please share your new object if you still have a problem

Comment: this happens when I'm working on something difficult and almost evrytime when i use spin mode

Comment: sorry, wasnt at home, i will fix it, thank u ♥